# How can i set encoded httplogin and httppass in the http request with CAMEL ROUTE?

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I try to send request to a webservice with camel and i dont found how to set httplogin and httppass
with simple java i can do this:

```
final String s =  my_httpLogin+":"+my_httpPwd;
final byte[] authBytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
```

and i set it in the header like this:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

How can i do this with Camel ?

this is the blueprint.xml:

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery">
  <constant>
      my_url_partams
  </constant>
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="Authorization">
         <constant>my_encoded_string</constant>
</setHeader>
<setBody>
  <method ref="configsms" method="convertparam(Exchange)"></method>
</setBody>
<to uri="http://my_link"/>
```

in the convertparam(Exchange) i just add HTTP_METHOD, CONTENT_TYPE..like this

```
public void convertparam(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,"POST" );
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Authorization information in exchange header. If you have encoded string already in the exchange, you set as follow in spring/bluprint DSL just before your http request

```
<setHeader headerName="Authorization">
             <!-- here you can use simple language to get the encoded string from body -->
    </setHeader>
```

if you want to do some java logic to get the appropriate username and password, just have a camel processor before http request. In Camel processor you can get username and password, encode and set in the header as below,

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: I did this but when i do: `<log message="${header.Authorization}"/>` inside blueprint.xml, the result is empty

Comment: can you please put  your code snippet. It ill be easy to analyze.

Comment: i also set ecoded string directly with `<setHeader headerName="Authorization">
             <constant>my_encoded_string</constant>
    </setHeader> <to uri="http://41.228.12.180/wbmonitor/send/webapi/send_ack.php"/>` </br> but i still have 401 status code and i think it did not recognized Authorization as http header authorization

Comment: whatever you gave is correct. After this line if you put a http tag with target url, it should work. I did the same for my project aswell. Just try to print "my_encoded_string" before you set into header to make sure it has some value

Comment: try to set http authentication policy. like "Basic your encoded string"

Comment: i did this  `<setHeader headerName="Authorization">
             <simple>Basic my_encoded_string</simple>
    </setHeader>` and i got the same error statusCode: 401